# change after successful delete flash message in flask-admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

how to change after successful delete flash message in flask-admin?

```
flash(ngettext('Record was successfully deleted.',
                           '%(count)s records were successfully deleted.',
                           count,
                           count=count), 'success')
```

To

```
flash(ngettext('Account was successfully unlinked.',
                           '%(count)s records were successfully deleted.',
                           count,
                           count=count), 'success')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only way to achieve this is to rewrite the entire `delete_view` method, and change the message to whatever you want.

If you want to do change the message for many models, use inheritance and create a method like `get_delete_message`, which will be called from inside the `delete_view`.